# Background icons / images to HTML table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to recreate the golf leaderboard look, akin to this screenshot from golfchannel.com, with circles for birdies and squares for bogeys.

[image]

The site uses Bootstrap for main content and styling, and PHP for the database & code logic.

I am within the loop that `echo`'s the table content (`<td>`'s mainly), and I have tried such as:

```
switch ($tmp['holeNettPoints'][$i]) {
  case 3:
    $img = 'background="assets/img/oval.png"';
    break;
                                                                                        
  default:
    $img = "";
    break;
}                                                                              }
echo "<td ".$img.">".$tmp['holeNettPoints'][$i]."</td>";
```

But the results are this repeating of the `oval.png` (a 32x32px PNG image) within each cell it is applied to, rather than 1 singular centred behind the number:

[image]

Have I taken the wrong approach? Are there other ways? Or HTML / CSS properties or methods to achieve this?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your background image is well set but repeating. Use `background-repeat: no-repeat` CSS on your cells. You might also want to center it...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: Thanks @julien.giband - part way there... the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` worked, however I have tried a few different centre methods but none have worked. So now it just looks like the 1st circle with the number off-centre to it. I have tried `background: no-repeat center;` and `text-align: center;`. `align-items: center;` is better than most, but there seems to be so many different ways to accomplish this... Can I ask for some more help please?

Comment: @biberman, my apologies, I thought the code exert provided was enough to provide insight to the problem & question at hand. Indeed, julien.giband has been kind enough to respond, and I have been able to progress with his guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Following guidance from @julien.giband and some experimentation, I luckily stumbled on a successful layout for my needs. This was the linked CSS file:

```
th, td {
    padding: 4px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I think there are many other aligning and other properties in the HTML and CSS specs, this just worked for me...

[image]

Comment: Cheers you did it! Sorry I wasn't available to give you more help